# ES5 with material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In the official website , there is a way to import the Module to the project

```
   import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
    import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

    <Button component={Link} to="/open-collective">
      Link
    </Button>
```

However is there anyway to call the object by **Browser global(window object)**?

Comment: Are you trying to access the DOM inside your component?

Comment: no , i want to create the Button  component without using import

Comment: Are you looking to create your own Button component? or do you still want to use Material-ui buttons, but not have them imported?

Comment: Yes i want to use Material-ui buttons, but not have them imported

Comment: Any luck with my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a CDN version, include that in your `index.html`, then you will be able to access it.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core/umd/material-ui.production.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

and the font file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
```

Here is an example https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/cdn

It should be noted according to their [documentation](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/)

> You can start using Material-UI with minimal Front-end infrastructure,
>   which is great for prototyping. We discourage using this approach in
>   production though - the client has to download the entire library,
>   regardless of which components are actually used, affecting
>   performance and bandwidth utilisation.

Comment: Thx for yr patient to reply my question . 
would you please provide the next step , can i call the <Button >
    </Button>  sth like var Button = material-ui.Button ; ???????????

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use the components as you normally would, see the example on the material-ui website, because ReactJS renders the components as normal HTML, and so the Material-UI library will be downloaded by the person who is using your website. So the component code will reference their downloaded version. Try it out.

Comment: i cant find any examplein the  website without importing components  ~_~
https://material-ui.com/getting-started/usage/

Comment: That's great, accept the answer if it answers your question, that will let people know the issue has been resolved.