# Material-ui components in ES5

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-5

Is it possible to compile the material-ui switch component to a format that can be used in a regular ES5 project?

If so what would be the level of complexity and steps?

I have no React experience apart from using create react app and adding the switch to a page that way.

Comment: I think you can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52088584/es5-with-material-ui)

Comment: Thank you! The code in the example html is ES6 unfortunately.